# Jquery hover out halting script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if ($navToggle.hasClass('active')) {
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            $navToggle.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            $navToggle.addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    $(".navbtn").hover(function () {
        $('.nav-toggle').addClass('hover');
    });
});
```

this works great but the hover is incomplete because whenever I add the `removeClass` line to it , it stops working ? Like so:

```
$(".navbtn").hover(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').addClass('hover');
    $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('hover');
});
```

please can someonne help I am only trying to reset a hover class.

Comment: Why add a class and then immediately remove it?

Comment: the class is the hover effect , so it does its thing then when you leave the area it resets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [.hover with two arguments](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1), first argument is for a mouse enter callback, the second is for mouse leave

```
$(".navbtn").hover(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('hover');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".navbtn").hover(function () {
        $('.nav-toggle').addClass('hover');
    },function(){
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('hover');
    });
```

```css
.nav-toggle {
   background:#FFF;  
   transition:all 1s;
}

.nav-toggle.hover {
   background:#FF0;
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbtn">My Nav</div>

<div class="nav-toggle">Toggle</div>
```

Note that if the element you want to trigger a css transition on has some relation to the hovered element you can just use css. So if for instance .nav-toggle was a sibling or child of .navbtn you can use the :hover psuedo class

```
.navbtn:hover .nav-toggle {
   background:#FF0;
}
```

**CSS Demo**

Assumes .nav-toggle is a sibling of .navbtn

```css
.nav-toggle {
   background:#FFF;  
   transition:all 1s;
}

.navbtn:hover ~ .nav-toggle {
   background:#FF0;
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbtn">My Nav</div>
<div class="nav-toggle">Toggle</div>
```